# graphite storage schema retention

Tags: graphite, retention, graphite-carbon, whisper

I have a question: I would like to keep whisper data for 1 year (7 days 5 seconds, 30 days 1 minute, 1y 5 minutes)

Is this correct:

```
[default]
pattern = .*
retentions = 5s:7d,1m:30d,5m:1y
```

How long will my data be kept? 1 year ? or (7d+30d+1y) ?

Secondly I would like to keep data for 2 years ( 7 days 5 seconds, 30 days 1 minute, 1y 5 minutes, 2y 1h

```
[default]
pattern = .*
retentions = 5s:7d,1m:30d,5m:1y,1h:2y
```

Is this correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Q1: 1 year, schema's overlap.

Q2: seems good as well.

Comment: so Q1 would also work?

Comment: yes, why wouldn't it?